# How to merge two tables with inner join in biq query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I think this should be a simple merge of two tables, but the Coursera course by Google in Big Query confuses me because I'm not sure whether the project ID should be in the join clause.

```
SELECT
  employees_name AS employee_name,
  employees_role AS employee_role,
  deparments_name AS department_name
FROM
  first-recovery-401910.employee_data.employees
INNER JOIN
# Should the next line actually be as following:
# first-recovery-401910.employee_data.departments ON
# Or is this sufficient (without project id):

  employee_data.departments ON
  employees.department_id = departments.department_id
```

> Access Denied: Table first-recovery-401910:employee_data.employees:
> User does not have permission to query table
> first-recovery-401910:employee_data.employees, or perhaps it does not
> exist in location US.

Comment: You have two `ON` conditions in your join. Also, best to alias tables to make this easier to read and write. `...from first-recovery-401910.employee_data.employees e join first-recovery-401910.employee_data.departments d on e.department_id = d.department_id`

Comment: And you might need the project id prefixed to the table name. Make sure you are in the right project id to begin with. I don't know if BQ is picky about backticks around the table names but you could try that too.

Answer (score 0):

Please use backticks around the table names. The join column has the same name in both tables, therefore in the `ON` statement, the table name have to be included. Please give the tables alias names.

```sql
SELECT
  employees_name AS employee_name,
  employees_role AS employee_role,
  deparments_name AS department_name
FROM
  `first-recovery-401910.employee_data.employees` as employees_tbl
INNER JOIN
  `employee_data.departments` as deparments_tbl
 ON employees_tbl.department_id = deparments_tbl.department_id
```

Or use instead of the `ON` statement the following line:

```
using(department_id)
```